# What is Form Field Type _combo_ good for?

Tags: form-fields-types

The [Form Field Type Combo](https://docs.joomla.org/Combo_form_field_type) doesn't make any sense to me according to the documentation.

It doesn't offer any configuration option to define a list of options.

If it's only meant to be the base for user defined field types, then why can you add it to your XML?

Or how do you define it's options?

Comment: I managed to update the documentation now, but I cannot confirm that the <option>s work?

Answer (score 1):

The source code shows that combo inherits from list, hence uses the same `getOptions()` method.

So you should be able to define options for *combo* just the same way as for the [List Form Field Type](https://docs.joomla.org/List_form_field_type):

```
<field name="fieldname" label="fieldlabel" type="combo">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</field>
```

Comment: I wanted to correct the documentation, but even after registering I don't have any rights to edit, neither to start a discussion there.

Comment: I'm having trouble confirming this solution, because adding <option> Elements doesn't have any effect in my Joomla installation, even after refreshing the cache for the extension and bumping the revision.